# SQL convert perfomance optimization in EF Core

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm trying to optimize SQL query, generated by EF Core. I'm using System.Linq.Dynamic.Core and Z.EntityFramework.Plus to construct the filters for query. I need to find the array of objects with IDs from my list.

```
string arraystr = filter.Value.Replace("array[", "{").Replace("]", "}");
Filters.Add(_context.Filter<TEntity>(x => x.Where($"new[] {arraystr}.Contains({exactName}.ToString())")));
```

filter.Value comes from UI and it's the string of IDs which looks like:

```
array["ef47913f-8960-46ad-f8ff-08d865b62242","1617bed9-4369-44eb-b605-08d895a537c9", ...]
```

"Filters" - is the list of BaseQueryFilter.

exactName - name of the column to filter by.

In results EF Core generates the query like this

```
SELECT [c].[FirstName], [c].[ID], [c].[LastName]
FROM [Employee] AS [c]
WHERE NOT ([c].[IsDeleted] = CAST(1 AS bit))
AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(36), [c].[ID]) IN
(N'ef47913f-8960-46ad-f8ff-08d865b62242', N'1617bed9-4369-44eb-b605-08d895a537c9', N'ebd998be-9262-40aa-b604-08d895a537c9', N'6f472069-bd82-4686-7381-08d89800b4ae', N'a688c8bd-c045-42bd-737f-08d89800b4ae', N'292bc19d-1d1b-49ce-7384-08d89800b4ae')
```

"NOT ([c].[IsDeleted] = CAST(1 AS bit))" is generated from entity configuration

```
builder.HasQueryFilter(entity => !entity.IsDeleted);
```

I tried to use another variant like

```
List<Guid?> array = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Guid?>>(filter.Value.Replace("array", string.Empty));
Filters.Add(_context.Filter<TEntity>(x => x.Where($"@0.Contains({exactName})", array)));
```

But it complains about the "Contains" method.

How to remove this CONVERT from query?

UPD1:
I tried to use this variant

```
Guid[] arraystr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Guid[]>(filter.Value.Replace("array", string.Empty));
Filters.Add(_context.Filter<TEntity>(x => x.Where($"@0.Contains(new Guid({exactName}))", arraystr)));
```

but it doesn't work. Maybe problem in predicate...

Comment: Please avoid vague phrases like "complains" and "doesn't work". Show exception messages instead.

Comment: In first variant array doesn't have "Contains" method. In second variant can't convert string to Guid, because exactName has "ID" value.

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise you to parse the strings into `Guid` first, rather than trying to convert the `Guid` column to string:

```cs
var guids = filter.Value
  .Replace("array[", "")
  .Replace("]", "")
  .Split(",")
  .Select(s => Guid.Parse(s))
  .ToArray();

Filters.Add(_context.Filter<TEntity>(x => guids.Contains(x.Id));
```

You can also improve the other filter with

```cs
builder.HasQueryFilter(entity => entity.IsDeleted == false);
```

This should hopefully generate something like the following

```sql
SELECT [c].[FirstName], [c].[ID], [c].[LastName]
FROM [Employee] AS [c]
WHERE [c].[IsDeleted] = CAST(0 AS bit)
AND [c].[ID] IN
  (N'ef47913f-8960-46ad-f8ff-08d865b62242', N'1617bed9-4369-44eb-b605-08d895a537c9', N'ebd998be-9262-40aa-b604-08d895a537c9', N'6f472069-bd82-4686-7381-08d89800b4ae', N'a688c8bd-c045-42bd-737f-08d89800b4ae', N'292bc19d-1d1b-49ce-7384-08d89800b4ae')
```

Comment: I tried to use this variant

```
Guid[] arraystr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Guid[]>(filter.Value.Replace("array", string.Empty));
Filters.Add(_context.Filter<TEntity>(x => x.Where($"@0.Contains(new Guid({exactName}))", arraystr)));
```

but it doesn't work. Probably in predicate...

Comment: That's not what I said, is it? You want `x => arraystr.Contains(x.exactName)` no string interpolation involved